# Can't read/write HKLM registry keys and values even with admin privileges

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm trying to read (and eventually edit) some keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE from my C# application. 
The app is **already started as admin** (I've created an app.manifest with requireAdmin), and it shows UAC when is launched. However, I can do some other adminastrative things but can't still access HKLM.

I get a System.Security.SecurityException when I use this code:

```
foreach (string s in My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.GetSubKeyNames)
    {
     if .....
    }
```

After many attempts, it seems that I can see a few keys (and values) but not all of them.
Maybe can I do something with setaccesscontrol, does anyone else have any ideas? I haven't find any good documentation about this online, everyone just says that I have to set admin rights via manifest file, but I've already accomplished this.

Comment: Which ones can you see? Which can't you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for this, is you are trying to read a *32bit* key from a *64bit* application or vice-versa. You can read more about [registry virtualisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization) here

You will need to use the appropriate bitness in your app, or use the following to *read* and *write* the *keys*

[RegistryView Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.8)

> Specifies which registry view to target on a 64-bit operating system.

with

[RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?view=netframework-4.8)

> Opens a new RegistryKey that represents the requested key on the local
>   machine with the specified view.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. It seems that using 64 bit view also shows 32bit keys in HKLM\Software and puts them in a key named Wow6432Node. However there was also another problem with my code because I was using an external try...catch  and I realized from "regedit" that I am not authorized to read HKLM\Security and another key named BCD0000 so the external try...cath immediately threw the SecurityException. Now I have an internal try...cath to just skip them